# Column not found: 1054 Unknown issue in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-migrations

I face this issue when display one-to-many relationship in laravel 4

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 
'subject_start.teacher_subject_id' in 'where clause'
(SQL: select * from `subject_start` where `subject_start`.`teacher_subject_id` = 1)
```

but i have reviewed the migration file and database table ,i seen this column called teach_sub_id. why laravel throw this QueryException.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: If its called `teach_sub_id ` and you use `teacher_subject_id ` in your query... Then you are trying to access a none-existant column, they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very confident that actually the teacher_subject_id does not exist in your table subject_start. You can doublecheck it if you open your mysql console and type in

```
desc subject_start;
```

This will display you all the column in this table that exist.

If it is your intention to use different column then you can change your Eloquent relationship like this

```
$this->hasMany("TeacherSubject", "custom_key_column")
```

Comment: me too Margus Pala I am very confident also , i checked  it from mysql console before.
also i checked it from  laravel Schema 
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('subject_start');
  
   teacher_subject_id not exist but when  display one-to-many  relationship between subject_start and teacher_subject
 laravel throw the above Exception

Comment: Awesome , thanks sir Margus Pala , now  i can get the relationship well
,sorry i can't vote your Answer i have no point enough to do that .
but till now i don't understand why that error is occurred
if you have any idea please tell me

Answer (score 1):

copy the query and run directly on DB. you will see if your query is correct or not.